# Why does the man say “evil against evil”?

Tags: the-exorcist

In the first part of The Exorcist, a man writing in a book says to Father Marin, “evil against evil, huh father?” And then the clock on the wall stops ticking.

Why does the man say this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As explained here](https://exorcist.fandom.com/wiki/Pazuzu):

> Although Pazuzu is, himself, an evil spirit, **he drives away other evil spirits**, therefore protecting humans against plagues and misfortunes. (In the film, when the Iraqi museum curator sees Merrin looking at the amulet, he says, "Evil against evil".)